# Krusader - progress window for copy/move not showing

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, kde, file-manager

I have just installed Linux Mint 19 "Tara" (Ubuntu Bionic derivative) and Krusader is not working as in 18.2 "Sonya" (Ubuntu Xenial derivative). Progress bar for copy/move is not showing and I see these error messages in terminal:

```
$ krusader
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/16/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/16@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/16/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/16@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/22/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/22@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/24/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/24@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/24/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/24@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/32/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/32@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/32/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/32@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/48/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/48@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/48/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/48@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/64/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/64@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/64/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/64@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/96/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/96@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/128/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/128@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/256/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/256@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/symbolic/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/symbolic/"
Trying to convert empty KLocalizedString to QString.
kf5.kio.core: Refilling KProtocolInfoFactory cache in the hope to find "mtp"
kf5.kio.core: Refilling KProtocolInfoFactory cache in the hope to find "mtp"
kf5.kio.core: Refilling KProtocolInfoFactory cache in the hope to find "mtp"
kf5.kio.core: Refilling KProtocolInfoFactory cache in the hope to find "mtp"
qt5ct: D-Bus system tray: no
qt5ct: D-Bus global menu: no
Couldn't start kuiserver from org.kde.kuiserver.service: QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown", "The name org.kde.kuiserver was not provided by any .service files")
kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
```

When I start to copy, `Couldn't start kuiserver from org.kde.kuiserver.service: QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown", "The name org.kde.kuiserver was not provided by any .service files")` and two other messages below appear.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you check your currently installed packages and make sure that the kde-runtime Linux package is installed (apt list kde-runtime). This package should contain the KDE kuiserver service (/usr/bin/kuiserver). This package will install the /usr/bin/kuiserver file and create a service file in the /usr/share/dbus-1/services directory called org.kde.kuiserver.service {;^)>